# Is there a way to mask sensitive information like password from REST query in Serenity report

Tags: serenity-bdd

[Sample Serenity Report showing REST query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhN7y.png)
Is there anyway to mask the password from the Request Body when displayed on Serenity Report? All other aspects of the report are perfect, only the 'Content Body' requires customization if possible.

Tried the Serenity.recordReportData().withTitle("test").andContents("trying out something");

However the efforts are more as we would like all the components of the REST query to be displayed in report - Request header and body and Response header and body. Wondering if there was any readily available methods.